# Regular expression passes and then fails alternatively

Tags: javascript, regex

This blows my mind.

```js
var rexPassword = /[A-Z]/g;

console.log(rexPassword.test('Password1!'));
console.log(rexPassword.test('Password1!'));
console.log(rexPassword.test('Password1!'));
```

This is the same exact regular expression testing against the same exact string constant, but the output alternates as follows:

```
true
false
true
```

What is going on here?!

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h4hgnx14/4/)

Comment: Get rid of the "g" flag.

Comment: You may benefit from [Reference - Password Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48345922/reference-password-validation/)

Comment: @ctwheels thanks + 1

Comment: @Jordan ?? Having a question closed as a duplicate is not a *punishment* or anything like that; your question simply **is** a duplicate, one that's asked quite often. If you click through the link, you'll see the answers that have already been provided for exactly the same problem.

Comment: @Pointy, yeah, that makes sense. I'm just a little bit jumpy from previous abuse I've received on here. I've been called names.  I deleted my comment. I'll delete this one two. Thanks again.